# Function that creates an array with subarries

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have a function which creates an array of subarrays. It takes three parameters: the number of subarries to create within the array (`numSub`), the number of times the desired value occurs within each subarray (`numValue`), and the desired value (`value`).

For example, if I were to call the function with `(3, 2, test)`, I would want the following output:

```
Array [Array ["test", "test"], Array ["test", "test"], Array ["test", "test"]]
```

Here is the function I have written:

```js
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    arr.push([]);
  }
  arr.forEach(function(sub) {
    sub.fill(value, 0, numValue - 1);
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

I have looped through the `numSub` variable and inserted an array into `arr` for each iteration. This was successful. (`Array [Array [], Array [], Array []]`)

I then use a `forEach` loop to fill each sub-array with `value` beginning at index `0` and ending at index `numValue - 1` (because the second occurrence of the value would actually be at index 1.)

The function does not work as intended, however. Rather than the aforementioned desired output, I receive this:

```
Array [Array [], Array [], Array []]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fill` on an array that has received the right length, like `Array(numValue).fill(numValue)`. Here is how you could do it:

```js
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  return Array.from({length: numSub}, () => Array(numValue).fill(value));
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are filling an empty array. It's still an empty array (nothing to fill).

You should construct the array of some length:

```
arr.push(new Array(numValue));
```

Complete:

```
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array(numValue));
  }
  arr.forEach(function(sub) {
    sub.fill(value);
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) only modifies array values. It does not add new ones. Use push again instead

```js
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    arr.push([]);
  }
  arr.forEach(function(sub) {
      for (let j = 0; j < numValue; j++) {
         sub.push(value);
      }
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`fill` will only work on indexes that already exist and its second parameter in your case should be the `length` of the array (which is the default value) and not `length - 1`. You can see it here:

```js
let myEmptyArray = [];
let myFullArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

myEmptyArray.fill(0, 0, 4);
myFullArray.fill(0, 0, 4);

console.log(myEmptyArray, myFullArray)
```

You could `push` an Array with the necessary slots already in place with `new Array(numValue)`. Something like this:

```js
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array(numValue));
  }
  arr.forEach(function(sub) {
    sub.fill(value);
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.push` method to add value into your array instead `.fill`, see working demo :

```js
function subarrs(numSub, numValue, value) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSub; i++) {
    arr.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < numValue; j++) {
      arr[i].push(value);
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(subarrs(3, 2, 'test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have es2015+ You can do it easily :

```
const subarrs = (length, subLength, value) => 
    [...Array(length)].map(() => [...Array(subLength)].fill(value));

subarrs(3, 2, 'test');
```

(Edited) after the first comment

Comment: Thanks @trincot for the comment!
I fixed, it should work as expected